# Issue with "fast-xml-parser" dependency in Mongoose package in NodeJS Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

I am encountering an issue related to the "fast-xml-parser" dependency within the Mongoose package. When I run npm audit in my nodeJS application, I get the following error

```
fast-xml-parser  =4.2.4
fast-xml-parser regex vulnerability patch could be improved from a safety perspective - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-gpv5-7x3g-ghjv
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/fast-xml-parser
  @aws-sdk/client-sts  3.54.2 || 3.186.2 || 3.335.1 || >=3.347.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of fast-xml-parser
  node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sts
    @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity  3.54.2 || >=3.347.1
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @aws-sdk/client-sts
    node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity
      @aws-sdk/credential-provider-cognito-identity  >=3.347.1
      Depends on vulnerable versions of @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity
      node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-cognito-identity
    @aws-sdk/credential-providers  >=3.347.1
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @aws-sdk/client-sts
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @aws-sdk/credential-provider-cognito-identity
    node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-providers
```

I am using mongoose 6.11.2

Other Dependencies in the application are as follows

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.2.4",
    "debug": "^4.3.4",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-jwt": "^8.3.0",
    "generate-password": "~1.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "jwks-rsa": "^3.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.11.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "newrelic": "^8.12.0",
    "qs": "^6.10.3",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.5",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.5.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "yamljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@stryker-mutator/core": "^6.2.3",
    "@stryker-mutator/mocha-runner": "^6.2.3",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
    "chai-nock": "^1.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-no-only-tests": "^3.0.0",
    "mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "mocha-prepare": "~0.1.0",
    "mongodb-memory-server-global": "^8.10.0",
    "nock": "^13.3.0",
    "node-mocks-http": "^1.11.0",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "pre-commit": "~1.2.2",
    "sinon": "^15.0.1",
    "supertest": "^6.3.0"
  }
```

I have tried to update the dependencies but the errors still persists. Any ideas how to fix this issue??

Answer (score 0):

try to update mongoose package to the version 7.3.0.
it helped me.